# Why my app doesn't appear in chromecast.com/apps?

Tags: android, publish, chromecast

I have developed an Android app with chromecast compatibility, i have finished all the setup on Google Cast SDK Developer Console, my app runs well on my devices and also in other android devices an other chromecast devices, is published correctly, but is not apearing in this List.

What more I have to do to list my app in this page?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a coding question, it would be best if you contact our [support](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) team; they will be able to help you address your issue and make your app appear in the right place.